# Send empty string or null to API in TypeORM and Javascript

Tags: javascript, typeorm, psql

I have an API in typeorm which translates to the following in PSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE id=myId AND unique_code=myUniqueCode;
```

I want to create a GET request using fetch but the unique code could be null or an empty string. I'm not sure how I would pass that variable in. This is the fetch I currently have

```
fetch("http://urlEndPoint/" + String(id) + "/" + myUniqueCode, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
    console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: what are you using for your api server ? You can pass `myUniqueCode` as `query params` and then use it accordingly in your api